# Closure type signature

Tags: rust, closures, traits

I am trying to add a convenience method to the `Vec<T>` type. I believe using a trait is the correct way to do this, but could be wrong. Below is what I have so far, which complains that

```
trait objects must include the `dyn` keyword
```

What am I doing wrong?

```rust
trait IndexWhere<T> {
    fn index_where(&self, f: Fn((usize, T)) -> bool) -> Vec<usize>;
}
impl<T> IndexWhere<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn index_where(&self, f: Fn((usize, T)) -> bool) -> Vec<usize> {
        self.iter().enumerate().filter(f).map(|x| x.0).collect()
    }
}
```

edit: removed bounds on T as I added them by accident

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively this can also be implemented by not using a trait object, but a generic type instead:

```
trait IndexWhere<T> {
    fn index_where<F>(&self, f: F) -> Vec<usize>
    where
        F: Fn(&(usize, &T)) -> bool;
}

impl<T> IndexWhere<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn index_where<F>(&self, f: F) -> Vec<usize>
    where
        F: Fn(&(usize, &T)) -> bool,
    {
        self.iter().enumerate().filter(f).map(|x| x.0).collect()
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
trait IndexWhere<T> {
    fn index_where(&self, f: impl Fn(&(usize, &T)) -> bool) -> Vec<usize>;
}

impl<T> IndexWhere<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn index_where(&self, f: impl Fn(&(usize, &T)) -> bool) -> Vec<usize> {
        self.iter().enumerate().filter(f).map(|x| x.0).collect()
    }
}
```

which is equivalent to the previous solution, but uses the `impl` keyword instead.

You will find that the Rust standard library implements such cases using generic types and avoids trait objects. You can look at the `Iterator::map` implementation as an example: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#682-685

Using trait objects has the side-effect of making your method use [dynamic dispatch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#trait-objects-perform-dynamic-dispatch) instead of static dispatch, which has the possible consequences listed in the documentation:

> There is a runtime cost when this lookup happens that doesn’t occur with static dispatch. Dynamic dispatch also prevents the compiler from choosing to inline a method’s code, which in turn prevents some optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is literally telling you how to fix your code :)

The signature should be:

```
trait IndexWhere<T> 
{
    fn index_where(&self, f: &dyn Fn(&(usize, &T))-> bool) -> Vec<usize>;
}

impl<T> IndexWhere<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn index_where(&self, f: &dyn Fn(&(usize, &T)) -> bool) -> Vec<usize> {
        self.iter().enumerate().filter(f).map(|x| x.0).collect()
    }
}
```

Also note that I changed `T` to `&T` in the `index_where` signature because `filter(f)` takes `&(usize, &T)`